# Ms Access Rank with two variables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a ranking of based on two columns (Class and ID). This will rank competitors (using a Chipno) in their own class for each course, based on the lowest time. The left 4 columns are input and the desired output is on the right hand column.

```
Class Chipno Course Time Rank
F23 2025827 A   0:08:20 1
F23 2025827 B   0:17:53 1
F23 2025928 A   0:10:54 2
F23 2025906 B   0:20:49 2
F23 2025810 B   0:33:36 3
F23 2025923 A   0:11:50 3
M23 1398276 B   0:23:21 3
M23 2025805 A   0:09:09 1
M23 1398204 B   0:17:27 2
M23 2025964 B   0:16:48 1
M23 1398249 A   0:10:02 3
M23 1398235 A   0:09:56 2
```

So far I've got tangled up in a correlated query as I wasn't sure how to include the second condition. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do this using a JOIN and GROUP BY:

```
SELECT  T.Class, 
        T.ChipNo, 
        T.Course, 
        T.Time, 
        COUNT(T2.ChipNo) + 1 AS [Rank]
FROM    T
        LEFT JOIN T T2
            ON T2.Class = T.Class
            AND T2.Course = T.Course
            AND T2.Time < T.Time
GROUP BY T.Class, T.ChipNo, T.Course, T.Time
ORDER BY T.CLass, T.Course, T.Time;
```

Or using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  T.Class, 
        T.ChipNo, 
        T.Course, 
        T.Time, 
        (   SELECT  COUNT(T2.ChipNo) + 1 
            FROM    T T2
            WHERE   T2.Class = T.Class
            AND     T2.Course = T.Course
            AND     T2.Time < T.Time
        ) AS [Rank]
FROM    T
ORDER BY T.CLass, T.Course, T.Time;
```

I have not tested these in access, but as far as I can remember I have not used any unsupported syntax.

**[Working Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a2b0/14)**

*Examples are using SQL Server as closest comparable DBMS on SQL-Fiddle. In addition, I have left your original rank in these examples for comparison*

Comment: Great! What I came up with today was similar, but when 2 values were equal it gave a larger place (eg called it 1, 2, 4, 4, 5 instead of 1, 2, 3, 3, 5)


SELECT Places.[Gender], Places.[Class], Places.[Chipno], Places.[PunchID], Places.[PunchTime], (select count(*) from Places as Places2 where
Places.[PunchTime] >= Places2.[PunchTime] and Places.[PunchID] = Places2.[PunchID] and Places.[Class] = Places2.[Class]) AS rank
FROM Places